# Openpyxl, Telegram. Selecting the active sheet in the for loop

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, openpyxl, aiogram

Using openpyxl I get the file(reading it). Using the cycle, I get all the names of the sheets. Next, I make a command by which I output data from the sheet

```
import openpyxl

from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart

from keyboards import reply, inline

router = Router()
wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename = "data/Inventarization 2023.xlsx", data_only = True)

for item in wb.sheetnames:
sheet = wb[item]

@router.message((F.text == item))
async def agent (message: Message):
print(sheet)
text = ""
for i in range (11, 312):
text += f" № {sheet['B' + str(i)].value}\n Дата ввода: {sheet['C' + str(i)].value}\n✏️ Серийный номер: {sheet['D' + str(i)].value}\n Инвентарный номер: {sheet['E' + str(i)].value}\n Наименование: {sheet['F' + str(i)].value}\n Кабинет: {sheet['G' + str(i)].value}\n Примечание: {sheet['H' + str(i)].value}\n\n"
for x in range(0, len(text), 4096):
mess = text[x: x + 4096]        
await message.answer(mess)
```

I tried to transfer the command to the loop, but it didn't help

Comment: **Its not clear what your question is.** Please [edit] and update your question making clear what problem(s) you are experiencing. Also be mindful of your code sample indentation, especially with Python. Some indentation can be guessed at but we don't know for example if all the lines after `for item in wb.sheetnames:` are part of that loop (it makes sense if it is but we have to make a guess).

Comment: If the issue is just with extracting data from Excel using Openpyxl, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) probably doesn't require the telegram code, just the sheet loop and creation of the 'text' and 'mess' variables. removing unnecessary code also helps others answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be much easier. In Router, it was necessary to use message.text instead of item

User moken is right that if openpyxl outputs everything correctly in the loop, then it's already in aiogram